# Run interactive script before reboot

Tags: linux, centos, reboot, rc

CentOS VM.

I got a script for updating firmware that I would like to run before each reboot. However, I want to get user confirmation before the script is actually run.

I put the script in /etc/init.d/ and created a symlink in /etc/rc6.d/  named `S10test`. But the script was never run. -- I tested it with `echo "test" >> /root/output`.

I also tried creating a file under `/var/lock/subsys` with the same name as the script. -- no success.

I then moved on to testing the POC -- if the script could be run, would it work? I tried some simple commands in the built-in `killall` script, which does get run. `echo` into a file works, but things like `read userinput` or `sleep 20` doesn't seem to work. After I run `reboot`, the server goes down immediately.

Two questions:

1. What am I missing in getting my script to run before reboot?
2. Why commands such as `sleep` and `read` did not run? Is there a way to 'pause reboot' if possible?

I'm new to Linux. Links to references or detailed explanation will be much appreciated.